# Proper way to do this in pandas without using for loop

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

The question is I would like to avoid iterrows here.

From my dataframe I want to create a new column "unique" that will be based on the condition that if "a" and "b" column values are the same I would give it a value "uniqueN" then for all occurrence of the exact "a" and "b" I would need the same value "uniqueN".

In this case

- "1", "3" (the first row) from "a" and "b" is the first unique pair, so I give that the value "unique1", and the seventh row will also have the same value which is "unique1" as it is also "1", "3".
- "2", "2" (the second row) is the next unique "a", "b" pair so I give them "unique2" and the eight row also has "2", "2" so that will also have "unique2".
- "3", "1" (third row) is the next unique, so "unique3", no more rows in the df is "3", "1" so that value wont repeat.
- and so on

I have a working code that uses loops but this is not the pandas way, can anyone suggest how I can do this using pandas functions?

Expected Output (My code works, but its not using pandas methods)

```
   a  b   unique
0  1  3  unique1
1  2  2  unique2
2  3  1  unique3
3  4  2  unique4
4  3  3  unique5
5  4  2  unique4
6  1  3  unique1
7  2  2  unique2
```

Code

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 1, 2], 'b': [3, 2, 1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2]})

c = 1
seen = {}
for i, j in df.iterrows():
    j = tuple(j)
    if j not in seen:
        seen[j] = 'unique' + str(c)
        c += 1

for key, value in seen.items():
    df.loc[(df.a == key[0]) & (df.b == key[1]), 'unique'] = value
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's use [`groupby ngroup`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.ngroup.html) with `sort=False` to ensure values are enumerated in order of appearance, [`add`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.add.html) 1 so group numbers start at one, then convert to string with [`astype`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.astype.html) so we can add the prefix unique to the number:

```
df['unique'] = 'unique' + \
               df.groupby(['a', 'b'], sort=False).ngroup().add(1).astype(str)
```

Or with [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) and `format` instead of converting and concatenating:

```
df['unique'] = (
    df.groupby(['a', 'b'], sort=False).ngroup()
        .add(1)
        .map('unique{}'.format)
)
```

`df`:

```
   a  b   unique
0  1  3  unique1
1  2  2  unique2
2  3  1  unique3
3  4  2  unique4
4  3  3  unique5
5  4  2  unique4
6  1  3  unique1
7  2  2  unique2
```

---

Setup:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'a': [1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 1, 2], 'b': [3, 2, 1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2]
})
```

Answer (score 1):

I came up with a slightly different solution.  I'll add this for posterity, but the `groupby` answer is superior.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [1, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 1, 2], 'b': [3, 2, 1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 2]})

print(df)
df1 = df[~df.duplicated()]
print(df1)
df1['unique'] = df1.index
print(df1)
df2 = df.merge(df1, how='left')
print(df2)
```

Comment: can you explain just this line? `df1['index'] = df1.index` as the next line does not seem to do anything with the column

Comment: That should have been called `'unique'`; I'll fix that.  Once I remove the duplicates, I need a column that provides a unique identifier for the remaining rows.  I do that by copying the index, which is just the row number.